# Is hint like feature available in pickers?

Tags: codenameone

I have some textfields where I use hints with light grey color. It gets dark black coloured when smth is typed here. Along with them, I have a couple of date and time pickers. I think hints cannot be set in pickers. I want the light grey color initially in pickers and when a date is picked, the dark black color should be there so that it matches with other textfields and the design. How can I get that in pickers?

```
    Picker startDate = new Picker();
    startDate.setText("Start Date");
    startDate.setUIID("eventTextFieldBorder");
    startDate.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xb6b5b5);
```

Comment: What language is this?  What library?

Comment: It is codenameone for mobile app development. https://www.codenameone.com/

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. Hint's are exposed in `TextArea` subclasses and while the picker uses the `TextField` UIID it is technically a button and can't be edited.

Comment: Is there any workaround so that I can set the picker text color grey initially and change it into black after a date is selected?

Comment: You can use `setUIID` and toggle it in the action listener.